# XML Parsing Error Using UTF8

Tags: iphone, xml

I  have error when I was parsing `xml` data. when we are converting `xml` data in `UTF8Encoding` format. then we are getting `NULL string`. But when we are converting `xml` data in `ASCIIEncoding` format. then we are getting a `string`. Can any one tell me what's the error?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Probably not without seeing the XML you're generating and your input data.

Comment: i use the specific web server for that

Comment: You should also start to accept correct answers or people will stop helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the file with a hex editor to verify that the "é" is indeed UTF-8, 0xC3 0xA9 ?

Answer (score 1):

I know, its too late to reply, even though it may help.
[Go through this](http://www.developerfeed.com/xml/common/issues/xml-parsing-failing-due-encoding-not-being-utf-8), it will help...